# How do I properly use or convert a PSD file for large format printing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, vector, logo

I have an image PSD file at 200 dpi at an image size of 11" by 11".   My goal is to submit a final file for large format printing.  The end product will be an 8 foot by 8 foot step and repeat banner/backdrop printed on a heavy knit polyester fabric.  My boss hopes that the image (the 11" by 11") will print at 20" by 20" and repeat on the backdrop, i.e. to make a checker board backdrop such as is used on the RED Carpet.  I am a total novice and am concerned about the final printing ... The image has a photo + text and some of the text is in a thin, light font.  Can anyone assist.  This is the very first time to do this.  The printing company is asking for a vector file preferrably or just an image at the highest resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Printing company is asking it to be in illustrator or vector file because it is easier for them to scale and Re-Scale according to the final projects specifications as per mentioned. Adjusting it all in photoshop requires many data and time for the prepress and it (fonts images) will not come crisp in scaling. If you are not familiar with illustrator that much; just give them a print out or a mock up with the scaling attributes then give them also all used raw materials (cropped images,fonts, if possible identify pantone colors used) that you use in Photoshop. The problem goes in re-positioning the files. coordinate with the prepress designer.